# How to set an IPv6 neighbour discovery proxy with Netplan?

Tags: ipv6, lxd, netplan

How can I configure the following commands in Netplan?

```
ip -6 neigh add proxy 2a03:4000:21b:44bc:1::1 dev ens3
ip -6 neigh add proxy 2a03:4000:21b:44bc:1::11 dev ens3
ip -6 neigh add proxy 2a03:4000:21b:44bc:1::12 dev ens3
```

I'm in a situation where I would like to access two LXC/LXD containers on a vServer from the Internet using IPv6. Unfortuantely, the IPv6/64 network assigned to the vServer is configured in a way that is unable to forward IPv6 requests without a Neighbour Discovery Proxy.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with Netplan on both, the vServer (my host) and the LXD containers. I configured the containers with a managed bridge for IPv6 access from the Internet. For container access I further splitted my IPv6/64 subnet using a /80 netmask.

If I manually add a neighbour proxy for each IPv6 address used by the containers and the LXD managed bridge, as stated in the example above, my configuration works.

However, I dont know how to achieve the same using the Netplan configuration.

Comment: Currently there is no option to add Neighbour Proxies directly to the Netplan configuration. However, according to FAQ in the Netplan documentation it's possible to add a post-up script.

Comment: I think it would be useful to write an answer with all the details on how to configure it in Netplan using a post-up script.

Comment: So far I've written and implemented a script. It works, but I'm currently short in time and did not yet find the time to carefully test it. I will add an answer as soon I have it tested.